# How to Remove Value from List<SelectItem>

Tags: java

How to remove value of "abcd" from `List<SelectItem>`.

```
public class Sample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SelectItem> list= new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    list.add(new SelectItem("abc"));
    list.add(new SelectItem("abcd"));
    list.add(new SelectItem("abcdf"));

    System.out.println("size  :"+list.size());
    System.out.println("List  :"+list);
    list.remove(new SelectItem("abcd"));
    System.out.println("List :"+list.size());


}
}
```

Comment: write the code of SelectItem class also

Comment: @Jhanvi SelectItem is a class of JSF

Comment: @Jhanvi its predefine class of JSF

Comment: Don't think it's possible without knowing the exact position of the element, or overriding JSF's SelectItem class to provide specific `equals` and `compareTo` methods.

Comment: are you storing the individual select items of the list in any SelectItem variable?

Comment: Do you have a JSF-related question or a basic Java question? If the former, you must define the requirement behind your code, as your question is completely senseless. If the latter, why did you choose this particular class? After all, I strongly feel that you're searching in the wrong direction for the factual issue you faced with JSF.

Answer (score 3):

try this instead:

```
list.remove(1);
```

Where `1` is the index. This removes the element at the specified position in this list.

If you want to remove the element based on its `state` like this :

```
list.remove(new SelectItem("abcd"));
```

You have to override the [.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and also [.hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) methods of the `SelectItem` class because : 
[remove(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) internally uses the `.equals()` to compare if the element exist in the list, if it does, It removes the first occurrence of `new SelectItem("abcd")`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem();
    selectItem.setValue("abcd");
    list.remove(selectItem); // Just call the remove method
    // If present, it'll remove it, else, won't do anything
```

Comment: @Jhanvi - both contains and remove are O(n). Why calling it twice when remove also check for contains?
Bad solution. Wonder why OP accepted the answer.

Comment: FYI: this does not work if you dont override `.equals()` in `SelectItem`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [`SelectItem` doesn't implement `equals()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.4/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.java). The only option I can see is to iterate over each element and determine the index, then use [ArrayList#remove(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `Iterator` and traverse over your list. Whenever you find a match(I think you can use the `getValue()` method of SelectItem), use the iterator to remove it.

Since you can't change the `equals()` method of `SelectItem`, use the iterator like this

```
Iterator<SelectItem> itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    SelectItem si = itr.next();
    if (si.getValue().equals("abcd")) {
        itr.remove();
            // You removed what you wanted, you can break here, if you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that SelectItem isn't implementing the equals & hashCode method properly. In such a scenario, you can either iterate over the list and delete the appropriate item, or keep a reference to the actual select items and remove that reference directly.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the code you wrote to work **you need to implement the `equals()`** method of `SelectItem`.

From the java doc of `remove` method:

```
removes the element with the lowest index i such
that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))
```

Notice the part **o.equals(get(i))** in the condition that was provided.

In other words - the implementation of `ArrayList` searches for the specific object to remove. How can it tell if a certain item is the requested object? Naturally, it uses the `equals()` method and if the item is equal to the item-to-remove you provided, only then it's removed.

**Please note**: In order to remain consistent with other collection operations, **you also need to implement the `hashCode()` method such that it is consistent with the `equals()` method.**

Answer (score 0):

In the context of JSF, a SelectItem is a valid option in a UISelectOne, when you use the constructor that takes only a argument, the parameters is set as it Value.

Try this code:

```
public SelectItem getItem(List<SelectItem> items, Object value) {

    for (SelectItem si : items) {
        if (si.getValue().equals(si)) {
            return si;
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

And use like this:

```
    list.remove(getItemToRemove(list, "abcd");
```

**This dont modify the list when iterates, it return the desired element, and after you can remove it or use as you want**

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
public SelectItem getItemToRemove(List<SelectItem> items, SelectItem item) {
    for (SelectItem si : items) {
        if (si.getValue().equals(item.getValue())) {
            return si;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getValue().toString().equals("abcd")) {
           list.remove(i);
           System.out.println(i); //checking the element number which got removed
        }
    }
```